# Displaying products from database in grid affects whole site

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm writing a site where users can view each others profiles and products for sale. I have the profile section complete and is working until I try and integrate the products section. It seems to bust the whole site.

What I'm trying to achieve is to grab the products from the database and display them in a grid with the person who uploaded the products username and description they added for the product. Eventually I will have a 5 star review of the product under the product image but that's neither here nor there.

I'm using the same code essentially as I did for the user grid and database but it's not working as expected.

My products page code is:

```
<?php
    include 'controllers/grid/products-grid.php';
?>
```

The products-grid page is:

```
<?php include 'components/authentication.php' ?>     
<?php include 'controllers/base/head.php' ?>
<?php include 'controllers/navigation/first-navigation.php' ?>     
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12 column">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                <?php
                include '_database/database.php';
                session_start();
                $current_user = $_SESSION['user_username'];
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE product_id != '$product_id' order by product_id desc";
                $result = mysqli_query($database,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($database));
                while($rws = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
                ?>
                <div class="col-md-4 column">
                    <div class="panel-group" id="panel-<?php echo $rws['product_id']; ?>">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div id="panel-element-<?php echo $rws['user_id']; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse  in">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 column">
                                        <img src="products/<?php echo $rws['user_avatar'];?>" name="products" class="img-responsive">                            </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 column">
                                        <h2><span><a href="product.php?product_id=<?php echo $rws['product_name'];?>"><?   php echo $rws['user_username'];?> <?php echo $rws['product_description'];?></a>   </span></h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My products sql page is:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `mydb`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET  utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE `mydb`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `products`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `products`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_firstname` text NOT NULL,
`user_lastname` text NOT NULL,
`user_username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`product_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`product_desc` tinytext NOT NULL,
`product_img_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`size` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `product_id` (`product_id`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- Dumping data for table `follow`
--

INSERT INTO `products` (`user_id`, `product_id`, `user_firstname`,     `user_lastname`, `user_username`, `product_name`, `product_desc`,      `product_img_name`) VALUES
(1, '1', 'MyFirstname', 'MyLastname', 'myusername', 'product1' ,'a product  by me', 'product1');


ALTER TABLE `products`
ADD UNIQUE KEY (`product_id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `product_name`     (`product_name`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `product_img_name` (`product_img_name`), ADD   UNIQUE KEY `user_username` (`user_username`);
```

And my user data sql file is:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `mydb`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE   utf8_general_ci;
USE `mydb`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `follow`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `follow`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `follow` (
`follow_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`follow_current_user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`follow_profile_user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`follow_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `follow`
--

INSERT INTO `follow` (`follow_id`, `follow_current_user`,     `follow_profile_user`, `follow_timestamp`) VALUES
(13, 'User13', 'Surname', '2015-10-10 03:09:58'),
(15, 'User15', 'Surname', '2015-11-10 03:33:43'),
(16, 'User16', 'Surname', '2015-11-210 03:41:58');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `user`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_firstname` text NOT NULL,
`user_lastname` text NOT NULL,
`user_avatar` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_shortbio` text,
`user_username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_longbio` text,
`user_dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
`user_profession` text,
`user_gender` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_maritialstatus` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_address` text,
`user_backgroundpicture` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_joindate` date NOT NULL,
`user_country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `user`
--

INSERT INTO `user` (`user_id`, `user_email`, `user_password`,     `user_firstname`, `user_lastname`, `user_avatar`, `user_shortbio`,     `user_username`, `user_longbio`, `user_dob`, `user_profession`, `user_gender`,     `user_address`, `user_backgroundpicture`, `user_joindate`, `user_country`)   VALUES
(1, 'me@gmail.com', 'password', 'firstname', 'Surname', 'default.jpg',   'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Firstname', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit', '1916-08-08', 'Student', 'Male', NULL, 'default.jpg', '2015-11-11', 'countryland');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `view`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `view`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `view` (
`view_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`view_profile_user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`view_current_user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`view_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=123 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `view`
--

INSERT INTO `view` (`view_id`, `view_profile_user`, `view_current_user`,  `view_timestamp`) VALUES
(65, 'blub', 'blubsworth', '2015-10-18 19:30:56');


--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `follow`
--
ALTER TABLE `follow`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`follow_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `user`
--
ALTER TABLE `user`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `user_email` (`user_email`), ADD    UNIQUE KEY `user_username` (`user_username`);

--
-- Indexes for table `view`
--
ALTER TABLE `view`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`view_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `follow`
--
ALTER TABLE `follow`
MODIFY `follow_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=17;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `user`
--
ALTER TABLE `user`
MODIFY `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=18;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `view`
--
ALTER TABLE `view`
MODIFY `view_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=123;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Do you need a http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php `mysqli_close()` between getting the user info and their product grid item search?

Comment: @Steve As in having to have a session started? No I don't actually, it's something I could and will probably remove. Would it make a difference at the moment?

Comment: Not a php session as in `session_start();` I am not sure myself as I am not a mysqli specialist, but I know if I made a new query without closing the old one it caused all sorts of problems - that is if it is a new query - either way if queries were not closed I got problems.

Comment: @Steve Oh I get you now. Can you point out the line of code for me though? I'm blind to it haha. Thanks!

Comment: `<?php session_start(); ?>` needs to be the very first thing on the page or that causes tons of error messages, but if I understand what you have here rightly, once you finish the part where you get the user data out you would need to add the mysqli_close(); just after you close the while loop. I am assuming that the products grid is a separate query with the same user ID to get their product grid with a different search for all products instead of `WHERE product_id != '$product_id'`

Comment: Oh ok I gave that a try but still no luck. That's correct yeah. The grid should be displayed the same way for every user though. As in the user id i have there should be the users id of the person who uploaded the product. Does that make sense? When I import my products sql file to phpmyadmin I get this error: SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

SET time_zone = "+00:00";# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Comment: Tchicky's answer on this page "can be useful if 0 has been stored in a table's AUTO_INCREMENT column" (no matter that it relates to Drupal) https://www.drupal.org/node/164401 might shed some light - I am out of my depth there and am getting urged to move to chat but don't have a lot more suggestions. Sorry.

Comment: @Steve No problem, thanks for the help Steve, much appreciated :)

Comment: You are welcome. Best of luck with your project.  Lots of multiple spaces in posted code - I assume they aren't for real

Comment: @Steve I don't believe it does no.

Comment: Looks like that could be the item with the problem though, as it is the only auto increment one.

Comment: I'll look into it. Cheers!

Comment: Not sure that you can set a value to an autoincrement field - I think it supplies the unique id automatically itself when a new row is created but might be talking rubbish. It just can't be 0